# Is it true that $aH = bH$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. The I know that for $a,b\in G$ we have $aH = bH$ if and only if $a^{-1}b \in H$.

My question is if it is also true that $aH = bH$ if and only if $ab^{-1} \in H$? Does it matter where the $-1$ goes?

I am guessing that this is not true since we keep putting the $-1$ on the left element, but I am also thinking that it might be true because they look like the same.

If $G$ is abelian, then it doesn't matter, so a possible counter example would have to involve a non-abelian group. If $H$ is a normal subgroup, then it should also be true because then $a^{-1}bH = Ha^{-1}b$.

Comment: I don't think that's true - it is true iff $a^{-1}b\in H$ or iff $b^{-1}a\in H$, but not $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: here's a counterexample. Let $G=S_3, H=\langle (1,2)\rangle$,$a=(1,2,3)$, $b = (1,3)$.  Then $a^{-1}b = (1,2) \in H$ so $aH= bH$, but $ab^{-1} = (1,2,3)(1,3) = (2,3) \notin H$.

(I multiply permutations from right to left here).

Answer (score 2):

No. This is why, in detail:
\begin{align*}aH=bH&\iff b^{-1}(aH)=b^{-1}(bH)\iff (b^{-1}a)H=(b^{-1}b)H=H\\&\iff b^{-1}a\in H \end{align*}

Now if it were true that, for all $a,b\in G$,
$$aH=bH\iff ab^{-1}\in H$$
it would imply that $aH=bH\iff Ha=Hb$ for all $a,b$. In particular, setting $b=e$, it would imply that for all $a\in H$, $aH=Ha$, i.e. $H$ would be a normal subgroup.

Comment: Presumably, that should be $b^{-1}a\in H$. This doesn't prove that $ab^{-1}\in H$ is not necessarily true, however.

Comment: It *may* be true, but it's not implied by $aH=gH$, unless $H$ is normal.

Comment: I know it's not true in general, but your answer *has not proven that.* You've just shown a different positive result, not shown the conjecture is false.

Comment: I supposed the O.P. did not ask for a counter-example, but was mistaken as to the  translation of the equality of cosets.

Comment: He asked "Is it true that Y?" You showed $X$. You did not answer whether $Y$ was true.

Comment: Remove the words "in detail".

Comment: @Nameless: Why?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I showed  it was equivalent to $X$, which implies $H$ is normal if $Y$ is also true. I added the details.

Comment: Still helpful in 2022 :D