# Why is there a bijection from cosets of stabilizer to orbit?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I'm going through the proof given for Orbit stabilizer theorem [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem), but, I am stuck at the point that there is a bijection from $G/ {\rm Stab}(x)  \to{\rm Orb}(x)$. Just before, they found that stabilizer is a subgroup and the group action function $\phi: G \times X \to X$:

$$ \phi(g) = g \cdot x$$

Breaks injectivity when $ g \equiv h \mod \text{Stab}(x)$. How does one go from this to the idea that fixing injectivity means to consider domain as cosets rather than elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $f: A \to B$ is surjective, then the preimages $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ for all $b \in B$ form a partition of $A$. [See [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mapping_Induces_Partition_on_Domain) for instance.] This automatically produces a bijection from the collection of preimages $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ to the elements of $B$.

In your specific example where $\phi: G \to \text{Orb}(x)$, you can show that the preimages $\phi^{-1}(\{y\})$ for $y \in X$ happen to be the cosets of $\text{Stab}(x)$. This is the crux of the "$\phi(g) = \phi(h) \iff g^{-1} h \in \text{Stab}(x)$" claim in the middle of the proof.

Comment: I got stuck at this few days ago and gave up, then, I still couldn't get it after searching for a long time but when I read your answer, everything just clicked! Thank you so much. Edit: How does one show that the partition sets in the functions domain correspond to cosets o_o

Comment: [Reminds me of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216088/is-it-true-that-ah-bh-iff-ab-1-in-h)

Comment: Ok, I figure d it out. Suppose we have a coset, $gS$ where $S$ is stabilizer, then element is of form $gS$. If we act this on an element $x$ , $gs(x) = g(x)=gx$. This works because the element s does nothign to x