# Prove that there are $g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_n \in G$ with $g_i x_1 = x_i$ such that $g_1 H, g_2 H, \cdots, g_n H$ are all the left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, group-actions, infinite-groups

Let $X = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$ be a $G$-transitive set and $H = G_{x_1}$.

It is required to prove that there are $g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_n \in G$ with $g_i x_1 = x_i$ such that $g_1 H, g_2 H, \cdots, g_n H$ are all the left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

What has been done:

Let $H = G_{x_1}$. Since $X$ is $G-$transitive set, for $x_1, x_i \in X$, there is some $g_i \in G$ such that $g_i x_1 = x_i$, for every $i \in J:=\{1,2, \cdots, n\}$.

Let $g \in G$. Remember that $\text{Orb}(x_1) = \{gx_1: g \in G\} \subseteq X$, but $\text{Orb}(x_1) = X$, since $X$ is a $G-$transitive set. Thus, $gx_1 = x_j$ for a unique $j \in J$, which implies that $g \in g_j H$.

By the other hand, let $i, j \in J$ such that $i \neq j$. Thus, $g_i \neq g_j$. Let's suppose that $g_j \in g_i H$, which implies that $g_j = g_i h$, for some $h \in H \subseteq G$. Thus, $x_j = g_j x_1 = g_i h x_1 = x_i$, which is a contradiction, since $i \neq j$ and $x_i \neq x_j$. This means that $g_j \not \in g_i H$.

This means that $G$ can partitioned into $n$ disjoint and non-empty sets.

Therefore, $K = \{g_1H, g_2H, \cdots, g_n H\}$ is the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $G$, all distinct two by two.

Is this proof complete and correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a bijection from cosets of stabilizer to orbit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415876/why-is-there-a-bijection-from-cosets-of-stabilizer-to-orbit)

Comment: Note that you can replace "such that" with "and then" in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $i=1,\dots,n$ you can surely find $g_i\in G$ such that $g_ix_1=x_i$.

Take $g\in G$ and the coset $gH$. We want to see that $gH=g_iH$, for some $i$.

The natural choice would be $g_i$, where $gx_1=x_i$. Since $gx_1=g_ix_1$ by definition, we see that $g^{-1}g_ix_1=x_1$, hence $g^{-1}g_i\in H$ and $g_i\in gH$. Therefore $g_iH=gH$.

---

As you see, the proof is much simpler than your attempt. And your final part is disputable: the fact you have partitioned $G$ into disjoint sets (assuming you actually proved it) doesn't imply that this partition is the same as with cosets.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not had the opportunity to experience the actions of groups, in particular, that if $g x_1 = g_i x_1 \in X$, then $\alpha (g^{-1}, g x_1) = x_1$.

Answer (score -1):

> Thus, $gx_1 = x_j$ for a unique $j \in J$, which implies that $g = g_j$.

This is wrong.

If $g_j x_1=x_j,$ then $\forall  h\in H, g_jhx_1=g_jx_1=x_j$, so $g=g_jh\ne g_j$.

Comment: It was supposed to be: which implies that $g \in g_j H$, because $x_j = g x_1 = g_j h x_1 = x_j$, for $h \in H$, or?

Comment: You wrote $g=g_j$, which doesn't hold.

Comment: That why I'm trying to fix my mistake Mr(s) MathFail. Instead of saying that $g = g_j$, it was $g \in g_j H$ for a unique $j \in J$.

Comment: No, it doesn't automatically imply that. This is exactly what you need to show: "If $gx_1=x_j$, then why $g\in g_j H$"

Comment: It got it. I need to prove that $1)$ for every $g_j$, $g_j H$ is non-empty, $2)$ for every $g \in G$, there is $g_j$ such that $g \in g_j H$ and $3)$ for $g_i \neq g_j$, $g_i H \cap g_j H$ is empty. Right?